# How to speed up rendering of an image on picturebox.image and other elements?

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a program and its form, onto which images are loaded from the network. To change the image, I press button.click. However, there is one moment, namely: after clicking on the button, in theory, the next image should appear instantly (the speed is similar to that of flipping through photos in the "Windows photo viewer")) only with very rare delays). And it appears, but with a delay of one or about one second, and in theory it shouldn't be like this, and there are similar programs of mine, on which it just happens as I need it, without delays! How and is it possible in this code to speed up the rendering / appearance of images on picturebox.image and other elements that appear along with it? Perhaps even in the code there are elements that should not be at all and you can throw them out of the code:

```
private void ricVision()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!this.locker && (this.waitVision.Count > 0))
                {
                    this.textBox2.Focus();                   
                    this.locker = true;
                    string[] strArray = this.waitVision[0];
                    if (strArray[9].ToString() != "-")
                    {
                        this.textBox2.Text = strArray[9].ToString();
                    }
                    int num = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[0].ToString());
                    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[1].ToString());
                    int index = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[6].ToString());
                    this.visionType = strArray[2].ToString();
                    this.Registor = strArray[3].ToString();
                    this.WordsTwo = strArray[4].ToString();
                    this.label7.Text = this.Registor;
                    this.label8.Text = strArray[4].ToString();
                    this.label16.Text = strArray[10].ToString();
                    {
                        if (label16.Text.Length > 5)
                            label16.Text = label16.Text.Substring(0, 5);
                    };
                    this.label19.Text = strArray[12].ToString();
                    this.label21.Text = this.BASE64;
                    this.label23.Text = strArray[13].ToString();
                    this.BASE64 = strArray[14].ToString();
                    DoubleBuffered = true;
                    if (label7.Text == "False")
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                        DoubleBuffered = true;
                    }
                    else if (label7.Text == "True")
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
                        DoubleBuffered = true;
                    }
                    if (label8.Text == "False")
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                        DoubleBuffered = true;
                    }
                    else if (label8.Text == "True")
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
                        DoubleBuffered = true;
                    }
                    this.label10.Text = this.visionType;
                    this.pictureBox1.Width = num;
                    this.pictureBox1.Height = num2;
                    this.panel2.Visible = true;
                    {
                        this.label13.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                        if (double.Parse(label13.Text) < 0)
                        {
                            panel2.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
                            if (label8.Text == "True")
                            {
                                panel2.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                                dataGridView1.Rows[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                                label13.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                                DoubleBuffered = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            panel2.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                            if (label8.Text == "False")
                            {
                                panel2.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                                dataGridView1.Rows[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gold;
                                label13.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                                DoubleBuffered = true;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    string s = strArray[5].ToString().Substring(0, strArray[5].ToString().Length - 9).Replace(@"\/", "/");
                    this.visionId = strArray[5].ToString().Substring(strArray[5].ToString().Length - 9);
                    this.visionThread = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[6]);      
                    this.label12.Text = strArray[7].ToString();                  
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);
                    string path = "";
                    this.pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
                    this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
                    DoubleBuffered = true;
                    this.ResumeLayout(false);
                    Form1 form = (Form1)Application.OpenForms[0];
                    this.ActiveControl = textBox2;
                    TopMost = true;
                    TopLevel = true;
                    textBox2.Select();
                    form.Activate();
                    form.Focus();
                    this.showCaptcha();
                    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
                    ImageFormat bmp = null;
                    Graphics gdi = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(s)))
{
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
}
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
}
}
```

Comment: "and in theory it shouldn't be like this, and there are similar programs of mine, on which it just happens as I need it, without delays! " it shouldn'd be like this. Did you check where the bottleneck is? putting an image as base64 inside an array, sounds strange...

Comment: Whats wrong with assigning the `pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;`?

Comment: The rendering could only be the culprit if the image were really huge; so most likely there is some other reason. Btw: You code seems to be stuffed with useless lines that probably stem from despair. Do remove all of them to clean up the program. (Example: All those DoubleBuffered lines make no sense, set the form to doublebuffered in the desinger and you are good.. It is only needed when you see a flickering animation)